# iOS: can I pair more than one bluetooth audio device at once?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I would like to write an iOS app to simultaneously record audio from several bluetooth headset microphones. Is this even possible given the api of iOS?

Comment: They can be paired, but can't perform the same task. Like you can pare them up to seven devices but only one of the devices can perform if all of them are performing the same task such as recording.

Answer (score 1):

The bluetooth specification allows up to seven devices to connect, but it's not straightforward, as it is dependent on the type of device and the service profile it provides.  For example, you can have a bluetooth keyboard, mouse, and headset connected at the same time, and an A2DP (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile) device to stream music, but you can't have two devices that performing the same service profile connected at the same time. check the link below for more info.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth

Comment: Ooo so I guess that's a no. My application involves connecting several devices all using the headset profile.

Comment: They can be paired, but can't perform the same task. Like you can pare them up to seven devices but only one of the devices can perform if all of them are performing the same task such as recording.