# ios BLE - connection to second device not working

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Currently I'm porting an app from android to iOS which will manage multiple devices of same type. Whenever I made a connection to the second device, the subscription to the first device would no longer work. I cannot receive any update from the first device since then. It seems that the connection to the first device was not working any more.

I searched a lot, another SO question seems to be relevant to my question. [iOS: can I pair more than one bluetooth audio device at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039396/ios-can-i-pair-more-than-one-bluetooth-audio-device-at-once). The only [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18039930/381646) mentions that

> you can't have two devices that performing the same service profile connected at the same time.

Can I communicate to multiple devices of same type simultaneously ?

**EDIT**:

Actually, I just found that it was a bug in the BLE code. The `CBCharacteristic` objects for the first device were released in a callback for the second device. After I fixed the bug, I could talk to two devices without problem...

Comment: Is it about BLE or MFi? What's your code? How do you connect?

Comment: @Larme BLE I think, the spec of the device does not mention MFi. The BLE code I'm using is from a plugin, it's a bit lengthy, I'll post the steps I do tomorrow.